# Setting sending account in Truffle test

Tags: truffle

I need to create contracts from various accounts in a Truffle JS Test. To do so, I set:

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
MyContract.web3.from = accounts[9];
```

Before creating my contract instance via:

```
let myContract = await MyContract.new("constructor argument");
```

However, the contract is still deployed by account 0 (`accounts[0]`).

How can I specify that that instance of `MyContract` shall be created using account 9?

I'm also interested in then calling functions of that contract using various accounts, so it's not just about deploying a contract using a specific account.

Comment: In case you've missed it, read the supplemental that I've added at the bottom of my answer; you might find it useful to your understanding of the system.

Comment: @goodvibration I have read it but thanks for the hint. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myContract = await MyContract.new("constructor argument", {from: accounts[9]});
```

Same thing for calling functions of that contract using various accounts.

You can use that object argument in order to specify various transaction details such as `from`, `value`, `gas` and `gasPrice`. It is optional (i.e., assigned default values if not specified explicitly), and it must therefore be provided after all mandatory arguments.

In your contract's code, those arguments will be available to the function via the implicit input argument called `msg`. For example, `msg.sender` will represent the value that you have passed in `from`, and `msg.value` will represent the value which you have passed in `value`.